# Javascript debugging enabled causes ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-5, ssl-certificate, visual-studio-debugging

I have an ASP.NET MVC web app running (.NET 4.5.2) and if I enable Javascript debugging, I get this error in the F12 console:

[image]

Here are the sources when the app fails to load:

[image]

If I disable Javascript debugging, the app loads fine and this is displayed in the console:

[image]

Here are the sources when the app loads:

[image]

I have allowed insecure localhost certs in chrome using:

```
chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost
```

Why does Javascript debugging cause this error and how can I get it to work?

**EDIT:**

This is what the console looks like when using IE:
[image]

Comment: Hi, what's the result if you debugging with IE or edge browser?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Please see the updated question.

Comment: `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost` worked for me on debugging Angular apps